# Triviality of relative cup product $H^2\times H^2\to H^4$ for spaces embeddable to $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a triangulation of $[0,1]^4$ and $A$ is a simplicial subcomplex of $X$. I would like to show that the cup product $$H^2(X,A)\times H^2(X,A)\to H^4(X,A)$$ is trivial.

It is realitvely easy to show that $H^4(A)$ is trivial, which was [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600560/nontrivial-cup-product-realized-in-bbb-r4/1602049#1602049).

All examples of nontrivial cup products I could find are somehow derived from attaching 4-cells to $X^{(2)}/A^{(2)}$ in a nontrivial way, such as in the case of $\Bbb CP^2$, or $S^2\times S^2$---but it seems to me that it is impossible to realize this all within $\Bbb R^4$. Any hint?

Comment: Wait, isn't $H^2(X) = 0$ (since $[0,1]^4$ is contractible)? This answers your second question immediately...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Probably you are right and I have problem with deeper understanding of cup product. If the map is "bilinear", then your argument works.. But somehow I don't see why the product of a global cocycle and a cocycle that is zero on $A$, has to be a relative coboundary.. But probably you are right and the product is bilinear. In that case, first question is probably much harder.

Comment: The cup product *is* bilinear, and satisfies identities like $d(a \smile b) = da \smile b + \pm a \smile db$. If $c = da$ is a coboundary and $b$ is a cocycle, this implies that $c \smile b$ is a coboundary too.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I see, I really appreciate your explanation and patience: I should have known. But I still believe that the other part is nontrivial (although I would be happy if that's easy too). I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X$ is contractible, $X/A$ is naturally homotopy equivalent to the suspension $\Sigma A$. (Explicitly, contractibility of $X$ allows you to extend the inclusion $A\to X$ to a cone $CA$ on $A$, and then you get an induced map $\Sigma A=CA/A\to X/A$.  From the long exact sequences on cohomology it is immediate that this map induces isomorphisms on cohomology, which is all we need here; it takes a bit more work to show it is a homotopy equivalence.)  But all cup products of positive-degree cohomology classes on a suspension vanish (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298938/cup-product-in-cohomology-ring-of-a-suspension), for instance).  Since $H^*(X,A)$ can be identified with the reduced cohomology of $X/A$, this answers your question.

Comment: Just for your info, we cite your response and thank you in the Acknowledgments in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06344) (to appear in [JoACT](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/journal/41468).)